Frontmatter fails to remove the Chapter numbers for Preamble pages
In compiling my Thesis PDF, I want to list the preamble pages 'Abstract' and 'Acknowledgements' in the ToC. The Abstract file is labelled as \chapter*{abstract}. When I remove the asterisk, it lists it in the ToC, but with a chapter number. How do I remove the chapter number?
The thesis.tex document I'm using is:
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany]{book}
\usepackage{quthesis}
\usepackage{apacite}
\input{notation}
\title{A \LaTeX\xspace Template}
\subtitle{For Doctorate of Philosophy Dissertations}
\author{Student}
\qualifications{Mathematics (Hons I)}
\supervisor{Professor  \and Associate  \and Professor  }
\email{student@uni.edu.au}
\department{School of Mathematical Sciences}
\faculty{Faculty of Science}
\university{Uni}
\degree{Doctor of Philosophy}
\keywords{dissertation, LaTeX, PhD, template, thesis,}
\flourish{} % Insert vector flourish here if desired
\logo{}     % Insert University logo here if desired


\begin{document}
\normalem
\frontmatter
\maketitle

\include{dedication}
\include{acknowledgements}
\include{abstract}

\tableofcontents



\mainmatter


\include{contributions}
\include{introduction}


\backmatter

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{citations}



\begin{biography}
% Insert your biography here...
\end{biography}
\end{document}

The abstract.tex file is coded as:
\chapter*{\centering Abstract}
% Insert abstract here

The quthesis.sty file is here:
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{quthesis}[08/05/23 PhD Thesis Style]


\RequirePackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{environ}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\RequirePackage{ifxetex}
\RequirePackage{longtable}
\RequirePackage{pgffor,pgfmath}
\RequirePackage{scrextend}
\RequirePackage{setspace}
\RequirePackage{wrapfig}
\RequirePackage{xparse}
\RequirePackage{xspace}
\RequirePackage{ulem}
\RequirePackage[varg]{txfonts}
\RequirePackage{booktabs}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
\RequirePackage[a4paper,margin = 2.5cm, centering]{geometry}
\RequirePackage[pagebackref=true,bookmarks=true,breaklinks=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    % Colors
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=RoyalBlue,
    citecolor=RedViolet,
    urlcolor=RoyalBlue,
    % PDF Viewer
    bookmarksopen=true,
    bookmarksopenlevel=2
}
\RequirePackage{caption}
\urlstyle{rm}



\newif\ifprint\printfalse
\newif\ifstrict\stricttrue
\newif\ifcalendas\calendasfalse
\newif\ifdropcaps\dropcapsfalse
\newif\ifnonumber\nonumberfalse
\newif\iffootnotebackref\footnotebackreffalse
\newif\ifverse\versefalse







\DeclareOption{print}{
    \PassOptionsToClass{openright}{book}
    \newgeometry{margin = 2.5cm, centering,bindingoffset=1.5cm}
    \hypersetup{
        colorlinks=false,
        allcolors=black
    }
    \printtrue
}

\DeclareOption{onehalfspacing}{\onehalfspacing}
\DeclareOption{calendas}{\calendastrue}
\DeclareOption{dropcaps}{\dropcapstrue}
\DeclareOption{footnotebackref}{\footnotebackreftrue}
\DeclareOption{nonumber}{\nonumbertrue}
\DeclareOption{relaxed}{\strictfalse}
\DeclareOption{strict}{\stricttrue}
\DeclareOption{verse}{\versetrue}

\ProcessOptions\relax



\makeatletter
\newcommand\subtitle[1]{\renewcommand\@subtitle{#1\xspace}}
\newcommand\@subtitle{}
\newcommand\flourish[1]{\renewcommand\@flourish{#1}}
\newcommand\@flourish{}
\newcommand\logo[1]{\renewcommand\@logo{#1}}
\newcommand\@logo{}
\newcommand\email[1]{\renewcommand\@email{\href{mailto:#1}{#1}\xspace}}
\newcommand\@email{}
\newcommand\university[1]{\renewcommand\@university{#1\xspace}}
\newcommand\@university{}
\newcommand\faculty[1]{\renewcommand\@faculty{#1\xspace}}
\newcommand\@faculty{}
\newcommand\department[1]{\renewcommand\@department{#1\xspace}}
\newcommand\@department{}
\newcommand\qualifications[1]{\renewcommand\@qualifications{#1\xspace}}
\newcommand\@qualifications{}
\newcommand\degree[1]{\renewcommand\@degree{#1\xspace}}
\newcommand\@degree{}
\newcommand\supervisor[1]{\renewcommand\@supervisor{#1\xspace}}
\newcommand\@supervisor{}
\newcommand\keywords[1]{\renewcommand\@keywords{#1}}
\newcommand\@keywords{}



\AtBeginDocument{
    \hypersetup{
        pdftitle=\@title,
        pdfauthor=\@author,
        pdfsubject=\degree\xspace Dissertation,
        pdfkeywords=\@keywords
    }
}


\ifxetex
    \RequirePackage[bf]{titlesec}
    \RequirePackage{fontspec}
    \ifcalendas
        % Calendas Font
        \newfontfamily\calendas{Calendas Plus}
    \else
        % Hoefler Text fallback (OS X), Windows users should change this to Georgia
        \newfontfamily\calendas{Hoefler Text}
    \fi
    \titleformat*{\chapter}{\singlespacing\LARGE\calendas}
    \titleformat*{\section}{\singlespacing\LARGE\calendas}
    \titleformat*{\subsection}{\singlespacing\Large\calendas}
    \titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\singlespacing\large\calendas}
\else
    % fallback to bold Computer Modern
    \newcommand{\calendas}{\bf}
\fi



\renewcommand{\maketitle}{

    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{singlespace}
        \topskip0pt
        \ifstrict\@logo\par\fi
        \vspace*{\fill}\vspace{-30mm}
        {\Huge \calendas \@title\par}\vspace{5mm}
        {\LARGE \calendas \@subtitle\par}
        \@flourish
        \ifstrict
            \vspace{12mm}
            \large{\emph{by}\\\medskip \textbf{\@author}}\\
            \@qualifications
            \medskip\\\@department\\\@faculty\\\@university\\
            \vspace*{\fill}
            A dissertation submitted in partial fulfilment\\ of the requirement for the degree of\\\@degree\\
            \medskip
            \normalsize
            \the\year
        \else
            \vspace{2in}
            \Large{\calendas \@author\\\vspace{0.2in} \the\year}
            \vspace*{\fill}
        \fi
    \end{singlespace}
    \end{center}
    \clearpage

    \thispagestyle{plain}
    \setcounter{page}{1}
    \begin{center}
        \vspace*{\fill}
        \ifstrict
            \textbf{Keywords:} \@keywords.
        \else
            A thesis submitted for the degree of \@degree at\\\@university
        \fi
    \end{center}
    \clearpage
}



\ifnonumber
    \renewcommand{\thesection}{}
    \renewcommand{\thesubsection}{}
\fi

% strip empty space in un-numbered section headers
\def\@seccntformat#1{\if\csname the#1\endcsname\relax\else\csname the#1\endcsname\quad\fi}

% strip empty space in un-numbered TOC entries
\let\latex@numberline\numberline
\def\numberline#1{\if\relax#1\relax\else\latex@numberline{#1}\fi}




\fancypagestyle{custom}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhf[HLO]{\slshape\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
    \fancyhf[HLE,HRO]{\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}
\pagestyle{custom}



\newcounter{alphachapter}
\newcommand{\noformat}[1]{\begingroup\def\\{}#1\endgroup}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\chapter}{ som }{
    % open new page
    \if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
    \thispagestyle{plain}%
    \global\global\@topnum\z@
    \@afterindentfalse
    \IfBooleanTF#1{
        % starred version
        % \chapter*{Title}
        \refstepcounter{alphachapter}
        \begingroup\def\centering{}\pdfbookmark{#3}{#3}\endgroup
        \@makeschapterhead{\raggedright #3}
    }{
        % regular version
        \IfNoValueTF{#2}{
            % \chapter{Title}
            \refstepcounter{chapter}
            \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{\thechapter}\noformat{#3}}
            \@makechapterhead{\raggedright #3}
        }{
            % \chapter[Subtitle]{Title}
            \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{\def\prefix{}}{\def\prefix{#2: }}
            \refstepcounter{alphachapter}
            \def\@chapapp{}
            \def\thechapter{#2}
            \def\thesection{}
            \def\thesubsection{}
            \@makechapterhead{\raggedright #3}
            \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\prefix\noformat{#3}}
            \def\thechapter{}
        }
    }
    % Insert headers
    \begingroup\def\\{}\def\centering{}\@mkboth{#3}{#3}\endgroup
    \@afterheading
}

% patch commands that call chapter*
\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}{\@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\listoffigures}{\@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\listoftables}{\@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listtablename}{\MakeUppercase\listtablename}}{}{}{}



\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
{
    \chapter[]{\bibname}% Correctly register in TOC and PDF index
    \list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
         {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
          \leftmargin\labelwidth
          \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
          \@openbib@code
          \usecounter{enumiv}%
          \let\p@enumiv\@empty
          \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
    \sloppy
    \clubpenalty4000
    \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
    \widowpenalty4000%
    \sfcode`\.\@m
}{
    \def\@noitemerr
        {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
    \endlist
}


\ifdropcaps
    \RequirePackage{lettrine}
    \setlength{\DefaultNindent}{0em}
    \renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\calendas}
\fi



\RequirePackage{listings}
\lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  backgroundcolor=\color{gray!2},
  basewidth={0.5em,0.45em},
  frame=single,
  framerule=0pt,
  emph={},
  emphstyle=\bfseries
}

% rename environments
\let\codeblock\lstlisting
\let\code\lstinline



\newenvironment{tightemize}
{
    \begin{itemize}
    \setlength{\itemsep}{2pt}
    \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
    \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
}{
    \end{itemize}
}



\newenvironment{verticenter}
{
    \vspace*{\fill}\vspace{-30mm}
}{
    \vspace*{\fill}
}



\newlength{\theparindent}
\DeclareDocumentEnvironment{quote}{ O{} O{center} }
{
    \let\doindent\indent
    \setlength{\theparindent}{\parindent}
    \def\indent{\begingroup\setlength{\parindent}{\theparindent}\doindent\endgroup}
    \begin{#2}
    \begin{minipage}{0.8\textwidth} \itshape
}{
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{}{\par\raggedleft\textsc{-- #1}}
    \end{minipage}\end{#2}
    \par\aftergroup\@afterindentfalse\aftergroup\@afterheading
}



\ifverse
    \renewenvironment{verse}
    {
        \parindent=0pt
        \obeyspaces\obeylines
        \begingroup\lccode`~=`\^^M
        \lowercase{\endgroup\def~{\@ifnextchar~{\\}{\\*}}}
        \vspace{-2mm}
        \begin{longtable}{l}
    }{
        \end{longtable}
        \par\aftergroup\@afterindentfalse\aftergroup\@afterheading
    }
\fi



\NewEnviron{biography}[1][]{
    % Open left
    \renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{
        \clearpage\if@twoside\ifodd\c@page \hbox{}\newpage\if@twocolumn\hbox{}%
        \newpage\fi\fi\fi
    }
    % Insert non-empty biography
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\BODY}{}}{}{
        \chapter*{\centering Author Biography}
        \thispagestyle{empty}
        % \begin{biography}[figures/portrait] usage
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{}{
            \begin{wrapfigure}{L}{0.3\columnwidth}
                \vspace{-0.9\baselineskip}
                \includegraphics[width=0.3\columnwidth]{#1}
                \vspace{-\baselineskip}
            \end{wrapfigure}
        }
        \BODY
    }
}


\iffootnotebackref
    \RequirePackage{footnotebackref}

    \let\std@footnotemark\@footnotemark
    \renewcommand*{\@footnotemark}{%
        \refstepcounter{BackrefHyperFootnoteCounter}%
        \xdef\BackrefFootnoteTag{bhfn:\theBackrefHyperFootnoteCounter}%
        \label{\BackrefFootnoteTag}%
        \std@footnotemark
    }
\fi

\deffootnote{1.5em}{1em}{\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark}\,}
\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\scriptsize}
\addtolength{\skip\footins}{\baselineskip}



\DeclareRobustCommand\onedot{\futurelet\@let@token\@onedot}
\def\@onedot{\ifx\@let@token.\else.\null\fi\xspace}
\newcommand{\abbreviation}[1]{\emph{#1}\onedot}
\newcommand{\ie}{\abbreviation{i.e}}
\newcommand{\eg}{\abbreviation{e.g}}
\newcommand{\cf}{\abbreviation{c.f}}
\newcommand{\etc}{\abbreviation{etc}}
\newcommand{\wrt}{\abbreviation{w.r.t}}
\newcommand{\dof}{\abbreviation{d.o.f}}
\newcommand{\etal}{\abbreviation{et al}}



\newcounter{reftype@N}
\NewDocumentCommand{\reftype}{ m m m O{s} }{%
    \def\thesis@labels{#3}%
    \def\thesis@delimiter{}%
    \setcounter{reftype@N}{-1}%
    \foreach \lab in \thesis@labels {\stepcounter{reftype@N}}%
    #1\ifthenelse{\equal{\value{reftype@N}}{0}}{}{#4}
    \foreach \lab [count=\n] in \thesis@labels {%
        \thesis@delimiter\ref{#2:\lab}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\value{reftype@N}}{\n}}{%
            \gdef\thesis@delimiter{ and }%
        }{%
            \gdef\thesis@delimiter{, }%
        }%
    }%
}

\newcommand{\chap}[1]{\reftype{Chapter}{chap}{#1}}
\renewcommand{\sec}[1]{\reftype{Section}{sec}{#1}}
\newcommand{\subsec}[1]{\reftype{Section}{subsec}{#1}}
\newcommand{\app}[1]{\reftype{Appendix}{app}{#1}[]}
\newcommand{\fig}[1]{\reftype{Figure}{fig}{#1}}
\newcommand{\eq}[1]{\reftype{Equation}{eq}{#1}}


Possible duplicate: Creating unnumbered parts/chapters/sections (plus adding them to the ToC and/or header)

@Werner I don't think so, because this would result in two identical bookmarks "Abstract".

The redefinition of \chapter in quthesis.sty is somehow strange. It does not support \if@mainmatter in the same way book does. And instead of using the optional argument as replacement of the mandatory argument for the ToC and the page header like the book class (and most other classes) would do, it uses the optional argument as a replacement for the chapter number in the ToC (but not in the page header). This works also with an empty optional argument and in this case, it even does not add a : after the number. So \chapter[]{abstract} would do it. So with the following changed abstract.tex (and all other files unchanged):
\chapter[]{Abstract}% adding `\centering` here is not recommended!
This is the abstract.

you'd already have the chapter:

and the ToC entry:

Note, that I've done my analysis of the problem and all tests without the missing files notation.tex, dedication.tex, acknowledgements.stex, contributions.tex, introduction.tex, and citations.bib.
BTW: Isn't there any documentation for the style file? Such important changes to the usual behavior of standard commands should be documented! Otherwise they are not only useless but confusing.

Thank you for your response. This does indeed remove the chapter numbering for the Abstract, but unfortunately also removes it for the mainmatter as well, like the introduction. The introduction.tex file includes the following: \chapter{Introduction}
\label{chap:introduction}
% Insert Chapter 1 here
\cite{Duchon:1977}
\cite{Hastie:Tibrishani:1990}
\cite{Ratcliff:Rouder:1998}
\cite{Newell:Rosenbloom:1981}

@Ron_S Please add a real MWE to your question or a follow-up question. But yes, quthesis.sty is broken, e.g., some of the changes in the definition of \chapter that should IMHO be local are global. The comment \chapter[Subtitle]{Title} in that file is also not really, what is does. Maybe you should not use that package or ask the author for help.

Thanks again for considering my problem. I've now added MWEs to a follow-up question that links back to this question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/728992/frontmatter-error-in-sty-file. I've asked the author for help, but would appreciate your help as well. Thanks
