Frontmatter error in \sty file
This is a follow-up question to Frontmatter fails to remove the chapter numbers for preamble pages
The MWE for the thesis.tex file is:
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany]{book}
\usepackage{quthesis}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\include{abstract}
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\include{introduction}
\end{document}

The Abstract.tex file:
\chapter[]{Abstract}

This is the abstract.
The Introduction.tex file:
\chapter{Introduction}

This is Chapter 1.
Using the same quthesis.sty file as posted in the original question, could someone please help me to change this quthesis.sty file to ensure that the Abstract is listed and unnumbered in the ToC, while the Introduction is listed and numbered as Chapter 1 in the ToC.
The quthesis.sty file is:
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{quthesis}[08/05/23 PhD Thesis Style]


\RequirePackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{environ}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\RequirePackage{ifxetex}
\RequirePackage{longtable}
\RequirePackage{pgffor,pgfmath}
\RequirePackage{scrextend}
\RequirePackage{setspace}
\RequirePackage{wrapfig}
\RequirePackage{xparse}
\RequirePackage{xspace}
\RequirePackage{ulem}
\RequirePackage[varg]{txfonts}
\RequirePackage{booktabs}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
\RequirePackage[a4paper,margin = 2.5cm, centering]{geometry}
\RequirePackage[pagebackref=true,bookmarks=true,breaklinks=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    % Colors
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=RoyalBlue,
    citecolor=RedViolet,
    urlcolor=RoyalBlue,
    % PDF Viewer
    bookmarksopen=true,
    bookmarksopenlevel=2
}
\RequirePackage{caption}
\urlstyle{rm}



\newif\ifprint\printfalse
\newif\ifstrict\stricttrue
\newif\ifcalendas\calendasfalse
\newif\ifdropcaps\dropcapsfalse
\newif\ifnonumber\nonumberfalse
\newif\iffootnotebackref\footnotebackreffalse
\newif\ifverse\versefalse







\DeclareOption{print}{
    \PassOptionsToClass{openright}{book}
    \newgeometry{margin = 2.5cm, centering,bindingoffset=1.5cm}
    \hypersetup{
        colorlinks=false,
        allcolors=black
    }
    \printtrue
}

\DeclareOption{onehalfspacing}{\onehalfspacing}
\DeclareOption{calendas}{\calendastrue}
\DeclareOption{dropcaps}{\dropcapstrue}
\DeclareOption{footnotebackref}{\footnotebackreftrue}
\DeclareOption{nonumber}{\nonumbertrue}
\DeclareOption{relaxed}{\strictfalse}
\DeclareOption{strict}{\stricttrue}
\DeclareOption{verse}{\versetrue}

\ProcessOptions\relax



\makeatletter
\newcommand\subtitle[1]{\renewcommand\@subtitle{#1\xspace}}
\newcommand\@subtitle{}
\newcommand\flourish[1]{\renewcommand\@flourish{#1}}
\newcommand\@flourish{}
\newcommand\logo[1]{\renewcommand\@logo{#1}}
\newcommand\@logo{}
\newcommand\email[1]{\renewcommand\@email{\href{mailto:#1}{#1}\xspace}}
\newcommand\@email{}
\newcommand\university[1]{\renewcommand\@university{#1\xspace}}
\newcommand\@university{}
\newcommand\faculty[1]{\renewcommand\@faculty{#1\xspace}}
\newcommand\@faculty{}
\newcommand\department[1]{\renewcommand\@department{#1\xspace}}
\newcommand\@department{}
\newcommand\qualifications[1]{\renewcommand\@qualifications{#1\xspace}}
\newcommand\@qualifications{}
\newcommand\degree[1]{\renewcommand\@degree{#1\xspace}}
\newcommand\@degree{}
\newcommand\supervisor[1]{\renewcommand\@supervisor{#1\xspace}}
\newcommand\@supervisor{}
\newcommand\keywords[1]{\renewcommand\@keywords{#1}}
\newcommand\@keywords{}



\AtBeginDocument{
    \hypersetup{
        pdftitle=\@title,
        pdfauthor=\@author,
        pdfsubject=\degree\xspace Dissertation,
        pdfkeywords=\@keywords
    }
}


\ifxetex
    \RequirePackage[bf]{titlesec}
    \RequirePackage{fontspec}
    \ifcalendas
        % Calendas Font
        \newfontfamily\calendas{Calendas Plus}
    \else
        % Hoefler Text fallback (OS X), Windows users should change this to Georgia
        \newfontfamily\calendas{Hoefler Text}
    \fi
    \titleformat*{\chapter}{\singlespacing\LARGE\calendas}
    \titleformat*{\section}{\singlespacing\LARGE\calendas}
    \titleformat*{\subsection}{\singlespacing\Large\calendas}
    \titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\singlespacing\large\calendas}
\else
    % fallback to bold Computer Modern
    \newcommand{\calendas}{\bf}
\fi



\renewcommand{\maketitle}{

    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{singlespace}
        \topskip0pt
        \ifstrict\@logo\par\fi
        \vspace*{\fill}\vspace{-30mm}
        {\Huge \calendas \@title\par}\vspace{5mm}
        {\LARGE \calendas \@subtitle\par}
        \@flourish
        \ifstrict
            \vspace{12mm}
            \large{\emph{by}\\\medskip \textbf{\@author}}\\
            \@qualifications
            \medskip\\\@department\\\@faculty\\\@university\\
            \vspace*{\fill}
            A dissertation submitted in partial fulfilment\\ of the requirement for the degree of\\\@degree\\
            \medskip
            \normalsize
            \the\year
        \else
            \vspace{2in}
            \Large{\calendas \@author\\\vspace{0.2in} \the\year}
            \vspace*{\fill}
        \fi
    \end{singlespace}
    \end{center}
    \clearpage

    \thispagestyle{plain}
    \setcounter{page}{1}
    \begin{center}
        \vspace*{\fill}
        \ifstrict
            \textbf{Keywords:} \@keywords.
        \else
            A thesis submitted for the degree of \@degree at\\\@university
        \fi
    \end{center}
    \clearpage
}



\ifnonumber
    \renewcommand{\thesection}{}
    \renewcommand{\thesubsection}{}
\fi

% strip empty space in un-numbered section headers
\def\@seccntformat#1{\if\csname the#1\endcsname\relax\else\csname the#1\endcsname\quad\fi}

% strip empty space in un-numbered TOC entries
\let\latex@numberline\numberline
\def\numberline#1{\if\relax#1\relax\else\latex@numberline{#1}\fi}




\fancypagestyle{custom}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhf[HLO]{\slshape\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
    \fancyhf[HLE,HRO]{\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}
\pagestyle{custom}



\newcounter{alphachapter}
\newcommand{\noformat}[1]{\begingroup\def\\{}#1\endgroup}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\chapter}{ som }{
    % open new page
    \if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
    \thispagestyle{plain}%
    \global\global\@topnum\z@
    \@afterindentfalse
    \IfBooleanTF#1{
        % starred version
        % \chapter*{Title}
        \refstepcounter{alphachapter}
        \begingroup\def\centering{}\pdfbookmark{#3}{#3}\endgroup
        \@makeschapterhead{\raggedright #3}
    }{
        % regular version
        \IfNoValueTF{#2}{
            % \chapter{Title}
            \refstepcounter{chapter}
            \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{\thechapter}\noformat{#3}}
            \@makechapterhead{\raggedright #3}
        }{
            % \chapter[Subtitle]{Title}
            \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{\def\prefix{}}{\def\prefix{#2: }}
            \refstepcounter{alphachapter}
            \def\@chapapp{}
            \def\thechapter{#2}
            \def\thesection{}
            \def\thesubsection{}
            \@makechapterhead{\raggedright #3}
            \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\prefix\noformat{#3}}
            \def\thechapter{}
        }
    }
    % Insert headers
    \begingroup\def\\{}\def\centering{}\@mkboth{#3}{#3}\endgroup
    \@afterheading
}

% patch commands that call chapter*
\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}{\@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\listoffigures}{\@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\listoftables}{\@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listtablename}{\MakeUppercase\listtablename}}{}{}{}



\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
{
    \chapter[]{\bibname}% Correctly register in TOC and PDF index
    \list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
         {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
          \leftmargin\labelwidth
          \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
          \@openbib@code
          \usecounter{enumiv}%
          \let\p@enumiv\@empty
          \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
    \sloppy
    \clubpenalty4000
    \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
    \widowpenalty4000%
    \sfcode`\.\@m
}{
    \def\@noitemerr
        {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
    \endlist
}


\ifdropcaps
    \RequirePackage{lettrine}
    \setlength{\DefaultNindent}{0em}
    \renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\calendas}
\fi



\RequirePackage{listings}
\lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  backgroundcolor=\color{gray!2},
  basewidth={0.5em,0.45em},
  frame=single,
  framerule=0pt,
  emph={},
  emphstyle=\bfseries
}

% rename environments
\let\codeblock\lstlisting
\let\code\lstinline



\newenvironment{tightemize}
{
    \begin{itemize}
    \setlength{\itemsep}{2pt}
    \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
    \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
}{
    \end{itemize}
}



\newenvironment{verticenter}
{
    \vspace*{\fill}\vspace{-30mm}
}{
    \vspace*{\fill}
}



\newlength{\theparindent}
\DeclareDocumentEnvironment{quote}{ O{} O{center} }
{
    \let\doindent\indent
    \setlength{\theparindent}{\parindent}
    \def\indent{\begingroup\setlength{\parindent}{\theparindent}\doindent\endgroup}
    \begin{#2}
    \begin{minipage}{0.8\textwidth} \itshape
}{
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{}{\par\raggedleft\textsc{-- #1}}
    \end{minipage}\end{#2}
    \par\aftergroup\@afterindentfalse\aftergroup\@afterheading
}



\ifverse
    \renewenvironment{verse}
    {
        \parindent=0pt
        \obeyspaces\obeylines
        \begingroup\lccode`~=`\^^M
        \lowercase{\endgroup\def~{\@ifnextchar~{\\}{\\*}}}
        \vspace{-2mm}
        \begin{longtable}{l}
    }{
        \end{longtable}
        \par\aftergroup\@afterindentfalse\aftergroup\@afterheading
    }
\fi



\NewEnviron{biography}[1][]{
    % Open left
    \renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{
        \clearpage\if@twoside\ifodd\c@page \hbox{}\newpage\if@twocolumn\hbox{}%
        \newpage\fi\fi\fi
    }
    % Insert non-empty biography
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\BODY}{}}{}{
        \chapter*{\centering Author Biography}
        \thispagestyle{empty}
        % \begin{biography}[figures/portrait] usage
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{}{
            \begin{wrapfigure}{L}{0.3\columnwidth}
                \vspace{-0.9\baselineskip}
                \includegraphics[width=0.3\columnwidth]{#1}
                \vspace{-\baselineskip}
            \end{wrapfigure}
        }
        \BODY
    }
}


\iffootnotebackref
    \RequirePackage{footnotebackref}

    \let\std@footnotemark\@footnotemark
    \renewcommand*{\@footnotemark}{%
        \refstepcounter{BackrefHyperFootnoteCounter}%
        \xdef\BackrefFootnoteTag{bhfn:\theBackrefHyperFootnoteCounter}%
        \label{\BackrefFootnoteTag}%
        \std@footnotemark
    }
\fi

\deffootnote{1.5em}{1em}{\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark}\,}
\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\scriptsize}
\addtolength{\skip\footins}{\baselineskip}



\DeclareRobustCommand\onedot{\futurelet\@let@token\@onedot}
\def\@onedot{\ifx\@let@token.\else.\null\fi\xspace}
\newcommand{\abbreviation}[1]{\emph{#1}\onedot}
\newcommand{\ie}{\abbreviation{i.e}}
\newcommand{\eg}{\abbreviation{e.g}}
\newcommand{\cf}{\abbreviation{c.f}}
\newcommand{\etc}{\abbreviation{etc}}
\newcommand{\wrt}{\abbreviation{w.r.t}}
\newcommand{\dof}{\abbreviation{d.o.f}}
\newcommand{\etal}{\abbreviation{et al}}



\newcounter{reftype@N}
\NewDocumentCommand{\reftype}{ m m m O{s} }{%
    \def\thesis@labels{#3}%
    \def\thesis@delimiter{}%
    \setcounter{reftype@N}{-1}%
    \foreach \lab in \thesis@labels {\stepcounter{reftype@N}}%
    #1\ifthenelse{\equal{\value{reftype@N}}{0}}{}{#4}
    \foreach \lab [count=\n] in \thesis@labels {%
        \thesis@delimiter\ref{#2:\lab}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\value{reftype@N}}{\n}}{%
            \gdef\thesis@delimiter{ and }%
        }{%
            \gdef\thesis@delimiter{, }%
        }%
    }%
}

\newcommand{\chap}[1]{\reftype{Chapter}{chap}{#1}}
\renewcommand{\sec}[1]{\reftype{Section}{sec}{#1}}
\newcommand{\subsec}[1]{\reftype{Section}{subsec}{#1}}
\newcommand{\app}[1]{\reftype{Appendix}{app}{#1}[]}
\newcommand{\fig}[1]{\reftype{Figure}{fig}{#1}}
\newcommand{\eq}[1]{\reftype{Equation}{eq}{#1}}


are you required to use that package? because it makes a number of obvious mistakes e.g. potentially introduces mysterious extra spaces in places you'd rather it didn't, loads package in the wrong order and uses obsolete or, at least, deprecated packages ...

the code is also weird and not in a good way. if this is an institutional requirement, complain to the institution. if it is not, just use something saner. why struggle with somebody else's mess? just because somebody sticks some code in a .sty and calls it a 'package' doesn't mean they know one end of a line from the other. this will cause you no end of pain. just don't do it.

Examples of a failures: (1) \PassOptionsToClass{openright}{book} in a package that is loaded after the class is useless, because you can pass (classic) options to the class only before it is loaded. (2) hyperref should be loaded after titlesec to be able to redefine several \ttl@… commands. (3) The \if in the redefinition of \@seccntformat should be \expandafter\ifx. (4) \noformat does not handle the optional argument of \\. (5) The whole \chapter definition is strange. It does not handle \if@mainmatter and the usage of the optional argument is unusual.

BTW: There is not need in your example to use separate files for the abstract and the introduction. Just move their contents to the main file to get a better minimal working example.

I've already asked before, but once again: Is there any documentation for the package? Currently the behavior of \chapter, i.e., the meaning of the optional argument and the global changes when using the optional argument, is very unusual. If this is not a documented feature it should be changed/corrected by the author/maintainer. Additionally the redefinition should handle \if@mainmatter also for the ToC entries.

There are several mistakes in the package quthesis.sty (see my comments to the question). The behavior of the new \chapter definition is unusual and strange. Especially, that the first usage of \chapter with optional argument changes the definition of \@chapapp, \thechapter, \thesection and \thesubsection globally and therefore for all following \chapter even without optional argument and all \section and \subsection within all following chapters not only this one is unexpected and very strange. If this is not a documented feature, I would call it a mistake.
Whether it is a mistake that with the new definition the chapter title itself respects \frontmatter, \mainmatter, \backmatter and shows a chapter number only in the main matter, but always shows a number in the table of contents may be arguable. IMHO it is a mistake. To fix at least this mistake, you can change
        \IfNoValueTF{#2}{
            % \chapter{Title}
            \refstepcounter{chapter}
            \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{\thechapter}\noformat{#3}}
            \@makechapterhead{\raggedright #3}
        }{

into
        \IfNoValueTF{#2}{% CODE CHANGED
            % \chapter{Title}
            \if@mainmatter
              \refstepcounter{chapter}%
              \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{\thechapter}\noformat{#3}}%
            \else
              \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\noformat{#3}}%
            \fi
            \@makechapterhead{\raggedright #3}%
        }{% END OF CHANGED CODE

With this change you get at least, what you expect:
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{quthesis.sty}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{quthesis}[08/05/23 PhD Thesis Style]


\RequirePackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{environ}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\RequirePackage{ifxetex}
\RequirePackage{longtable}
\RequirePackage{pgffor,pgfmath}
\RequirePackage{scrextend}
\RequirePackage{setspace}
\RequirePackage{wrapfig}
\RequirePackage{xparse}
\RequirePackage{xspace}
\RequirePackage{ulem}
\RequirePackage[varg]{txfonts}
\RequirePackage{booktabs}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
\RequirePackage[a4paper,margin = 2.5cm, centering]{geometry}
\RequirePackage[pagebackref=true,bookmarks=true,breaklinks=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    % Colors
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=RoyalBlue,
    citecolor=RedViolet,
    urlcolor=RoyalBlue,
    % PDF Viewer
    bookmarksopen=true,
    bookmarksopenlevel=2
}
\RequirePackage{caption}
\urlstyle{rm}



\newif\ifprint\printfalse
\newif\ifstrict\stricttrue
\newif\ifcalendas\calendasfalse
\newif\ifdropcaps\dropcapsfalse
\newif\ifnonumber\nonumberfalse
\newif\iffootnotebackref\footnotebackreffalse
\newif\ifverse\versefalse







\DeclareOption{print}{
    \PassOptionsToClass{openright}{book}
    \newgeometry{margin = 2.5cm, centering,bindingoffset=1.5cm}
    \hypersetup{
        colorlinks=false,
        allcolors=black
    }
    \printtrue
}

\DeclareOption{onehalfspacing}{\onehalfspacing}
\DeclareOption{calendas}{\calendastrue}
\DeclareOption{dropcaps}{\dropcapstrue}
\DeclareOption{footnotebackref}{\footnotebackreftrue}
\DeclareOption{nonumber}{\nonumbertrue}
\DeclareOption{relaxed}{\strictfalse}
\DeclareOption{strict}{\stricttrue}
\DeclareOption{verse}{\versetrue}

\ProcessOptions\relax



\makeatletter
\newcommand\subtitle[1]{\renewcommand\@subtitle{#1\xspace}}
\newcommand\@subtitle{}
\newcommand\flourish[1]{\renewcommand\@flourish{#1}}
\newcommand\@flourish{}
\newcommand\logo[1]{\renewcommand\@logo{#1}}
\newcommand\@logo{}
\newcommand\email[1]{\renewcommand\@email{\href{mailto:#1}{#1}\xspace}}
\newcommand\@email{}
\newcommand\university[1]{\renewcommand\@university{#1\xspace}}
\newcommand\@university{}
\newcommand\faculty[1]{\renewcommand\@faculty{#1\xspace}}
\newcommand\@faculty{}
\newcommand\department[1]{\renewcommand\@department{#1\xspace}}
\newcommand\@department{}
\newcommand\qualifications[1]{\renewcommand\@qualifications{#1\xspace}}
\newcommand\@qualifications{}
\newcommand\degree[1]{\renewcommand\@degree{#1\xspace}}
\newcommand\@degree{}
\newcommand\supervisor[1]{\renewcommand\@supervisor{#1\xspace}}
\newcommand\@supervisor{}
\newcommand\keywords[1]{\renewcommand\@keywords{#1}}
\newcommand\@keywords{}



\AtBeginDocument{
    \hypersetup{
        pdftitle=\@title,
        pdfauthor=\@author,
        pdfsubject=\degree\xspace Dissertation,
        pdfkeywords=\@keywords
    }
}


\ifxetex
    \RequirePackage[bf]{titlesec}
    \RequirePackage{fontspec}
    \ifcalendas
        % Calendas Font
        \newfontfamily\calendas{Calendas Plus}
    \else
        % Hoefler Text fallback (OS X), Windows users should change this to Georgia
        \newfontfamily\calendas{Hoefler Text}
    \fi
    \titleformat*{\chapter}{\singlespacing\LARGE\calendas}
    \titleformat*{\section}{\singlespacing\LARGE\calendas}
    \titleformat*{\subsection}{\singlespacing\Large\calendas}
    \titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\singlespacing\large\calendas}
\else
    % fallback to bold Computer Modern
    \newcommand{\calendas}{\bf}
\fi



\renewcommand{\maketitle}{

    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{singlespace}
        \topskip0pt
        \ifstrict\@logo\par\fi
        \vspace*{\fill}\vspace{-30mm}
        {\Huge \calendas \@title\par}\vspace{5mm}
        {\LARGE \calendas \@subtitle\par}
        \@flourish
        \ifstrict
            \vspace{12mm}
            \large{\emph{by}\\\medskip \textbf{\@author}}\\
            \@qualifications
            \medskip\\\@department\\\@faculty\\\@university\\
            \vspace*{\fill}
            A dissertation submitted in partial fulfilment\\ of the requirement for the degree of\\\@degree\\
            \medskip
            \normalsize
            \the\year
        \else
            \vspace{2in}
            \Large{\calendas \@author\\\vspace{0.2in} \the\year}
            \vspace*{\fill}
        \fi
    \end{singlespace}
    \end{center}
    \clearpage

    \thispagestyle{plain}
    \setcounter{page}{1}
    \begin{center}
        \vspace*{\fill}
        \ifstrict
            \textbf{Keywords:} \@keywords.
        \else
            A thesis submitted for the degree of \@degree at\\\@university
        \fi
    \end{center}
    \clearpage
}



\ifnonumber
    \renewcommand{\thesection}{}
    \renewcommand{\thesubsection}{}
\fi

% strip empty space in un-numbered section headers
\def\@seccntformat#1{\if\csname the#1\endcsname\relax\else\csname the#1\endcsname\quad\fi}

% strip empty space in un-numbered TOC entries
\let\latex@numberline\numberline
\def\numberline#1{\if\relax#1\relax\else\latex@numberline{#1}\fi}




\fancypagestyle{custom}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhf[HLO]{\slshape\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
    \fancyhf[HLE,HRO]{\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}
\pagestyle{custom}



\newcounter{alphachapter}
\newcommand{\noformat}[1]{\begingroup\def\\{}#1\endgroup}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\chapter}{ som }{
    % open new page
    \if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
    \thispagestyle{plain}%
    \global\global\@topnum\z@
    \@afterindentfalse
    \IfBooleanTF#1{
        % starred version
        % \chapter*{Title}
        \refstepcounter{alphachapter}
        \begingroup\def\centering{}\pdfbookmark{#3}{#3}\endgroup
        \@makeschapterhead{\raggedright #3}
    }{
        % regular version
        \IfNoValueTF{#2}{% CHANGED CODE
            % \chapter{Title}
            \if@mainmatter
              \refstepcounter{chapter}%
              \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{\thechapter}\noformat{#3}}%
            \else
              \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\noformat{#3}}%
            \fi
            \@makechapterhead{\raggedright #3}%
        }{% END OF CHANGED CODE
            % \chapter[Subtitle]{Title}
            \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{\def\prefix{}}{\def\prefix{#2: }}
            \refstepcounter{alphachapter}
            \def\@chapapp{}
            \def\thechapter{#2}
            \def\thesection{}
            \def\thesubsection{}
            \@makechapterhead{\raggedright #3}
            \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\prefix\noformat{#3}}
            \def\thechapter{}
        }
    }
    % Insert headers
    \begingroup\def\\{}\def\centering{}\@mkboth{#3}{#3}\endgroup
    \@afterheading
}

% patch commands that call chapter*
\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}{\@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\listoffigures}{\@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\listoftables}{\@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listtablename}{\MakeUppercase\listtablename}}{}{}{}



\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
{
    \chapter[]{\bibname}% Correctly register in TOC and PDF index
    \list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
         {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
          \leftmargin\labelwidth
          \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
          \@openbib@code
          \usecounter{enumiv}%
          \let\p@enumiv\@empty
          \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
    \sloppy
    \clubpenalty4000
    \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
    \widowpenalty4000%
    \sfcode`\.\@m
}{
    \def\@noitemerr
        {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
    \endlist
}


\ifdropcaps
    \RequirePackage{lettrine}
    \setlength{\DefaultNindent}{0em}
    \renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\calendas}
\fi



\RequirePackage{listings}
\lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  backgroundcolor=\color{gray!2},
  basewidth={0.5em,0.45em},
  frame=single,
  framerule=0pt,
  emph={},
  emphstyle=\bfseries
}

% rename environments
\let\codeblock\lstlisting
\let\code\lstinline



\newenvironment{tightemize}
{
    \begin{itemize}
    \setlength{\itemsep}{2pt}
    \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
    \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
}{
    \end{itemize}
}



\newenvironment{verticenter}
{
    \vspace*{\fill}\vspace{-30mm}
}{
    \vspace*{\fill}
}



\newlength{\theparindent}
\DeclareDocumentEnvironment{quote}{ O{} O{center} }
{
    \let\doindent\indent
    \setlength{\theparindent}{\parindent}
    \def\indent{\begingroup\setlength{\parindent}{\theparindent}\doindent\endgroup}
    \begin{#2}
    \begin{minipage}{0.8\textwidth} \itshape
}{
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{}{\par\raggedleft\textsc{-- #1}}
    \end{minipage}\end{#2}
    \par\aftergroup\@afterindentfalse\aftergroup\@afterheading
}



\ifverse
    \renewenvironment{verse}
    {
        \parindent=0pt
        \obeyspaces\obeylines
        \begingroup\lccode`~=`\^^M
        \lowercase{\endgroup\def~{\@ifnextchar~{\\}{\\*}}}
        \vspace{-2mm}
        \begin{longtable}{l}
    }{
        \end{longtable}
        \par\aftergroup\@afterindentfalse\aftergroup\@afterheading
    }
\fi



\NewEnviron{biography}[1][]{
    % Open left
    \renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{
        \clearpage\if@twoside\ifodd\c@page \hbox{}\newpage\if@twocolumn\hbox{}%
        \newpage\fi\fi\fi
    }
    % Insert non-empty biography
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\BODY}{}}{}{
        \chapter*{\centering Author Biography}
        \thispagestyle{empty}
        % \begin{biography}[figures/portrait] usage
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{}{
            \begin{wrapfigure}{L}{0.3\columnwidth}
                \vspace{-0.9\baselineskip}
                \includegraphics[width=0.3\columnwidth]{#1}
                \vspace{-\baselineskip}
            \end{wrapfigure}
        }
        \BODY
    }
}


\iffootnotebackref
    \RequirePackage{footnotebackref}

    \let\std@footnotemark\@footnotemark
    \renewcommand*{\@footnotemark}{%
        \refstepcounter{BackrefHyperFootnoteCounter}%
        \xdef\BackrefFootnoteTag{bhfn:\theBackrefHyperFootnoteCounter}%
        \label{\BackrefFootnoteTag}%
        \std@footnotemark
    }
\fi

\deffootnote{1.5em}{1em}{\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark}\,}
\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\scriptsize}
\addtolength{\skip\footins}{\baselineskip}



\DeclareRobustCommand\onedot{\futurelet\@let@token\@onedot}
\def\@onedot{\ifx\@let@token.\else.\null\fi\xspace}
\newcommand{\abbreviation}[1]{\emph{#1}\onedot}
\newcommand{\ie}{\abbreviation{i.e}}
\newcommand{\eg}{\abbreviation{e.g}}
\newcommand{\cf}{\abbreviation{c.f}}
\newcommand{\etc}{\abbreviation{etc}}
\newcommand{\wrt}{\abbreviation{w.r.t}}
\newcommand{\dof}{\abbreviation{d.o.f}}
\newcommand{\etal}{\abbreviation{et al}}



\newcounter{reftype@N}
\NewDocumentCommand{\reftype}{ m m m O{s} }{%
    \def\thesis@labels{#3}%
    \def\thesis@delimiter{}%
    \setcounter{reftype@N}{-1}%
    \foreach \lab in \thesis@labels {\stepcounter{reftype@N}}%
    #1\ifthenelse{\equal{\value{reftype@N}}{0}}{}{#4}
    \foreach \lab [count=\n] in \thesis@labels {%
        \thesis@delimiter\ref{#2:\lab}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\value{reftype@N}}{\n}}{%
            \gdef\thesis@delimiter{ and }%
        }{%
            \gdef\thesis@delimiter{, }%
        }%
    }%
}

\newcommand{\chap}[1]{\reftype{Chapter}{chap}{#1}}
\renewcommand{\sec}[1]{\reftype{Section}{sec}{#1}}
\newcommand{\subsec}[1]{\reftype{Section}{subsec}{#1}}
\newcommand{\app}[1]{\reftype{Appendix}{app}{#1}[]}
\newcommand{\fig}[1]{\reftype{Figure}{fig}{#1}}
\newcommand{\eq}[1]{\reftype{Equation}{eq}{#1}}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany]{book}
\usepackage{quthesis}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\chapter{Abstract}% NO OPTIONAL ARGUMENT!!!
This is the abstract.
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}
This is the introduction.
\end{document}




But note: After this change the strange and unusual behavior of \chapter[…]{…} is not changed. So you still should not use \chapter with optional argument if you don't want its global changes even for following \chapters without optional argument. Because of this and because of all the other issues with the package, the change is only a kind of hotfix for one single mis-feature of the package. I still would recommend to not use the package if you are not required to use it. You may be able to use some parts of the code. But others could and should be implemented in other ways if they are needed. The chapter implementation is IMHO one of it.

Additional note: This question is not a duplicate of Creating unnumbered parts/chapters/sections (plus adding them to the ToC and/or header), because of the explicit bookmark code in the star variant definition of \chapter in quthesis.sty
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany]{book}
\usepackage{quthesis}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\chapter*{Abstract}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
\markboth{Abstract}{}
This is the abstract.
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}
This is the introduction.
\end{document}

would result in doubled bookmarks:


Thank you so much for your detailed feedback. I will use the changes you recommended. I don't need to use this template and style file, but I've already generated my thesis on the template and received feedback to include the preamble pages in the ToC. I will provide feedback to my institution regarding the style file.
